# c++Bank project; How to read a set of strings as individual floats and add them

Tags: c++, visual-c++, express

Problem statement:
C++ program that reads a customer’s checking account information calculates his/her account balance. 
menu based application should be
developed to perform the following
functionalities iteratively until the user request to quit the program:
1. Display, 2. Deposit, 3. Withdraw, 4. Quit.

This is what I have so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//Main function
int main()
{ 
    //Identify type variables
    int x=0;
    float amountinput,famount,sum;
    string firstname, lastname,date,filename,input,ID,amount;
    fstream file;
//Program loop
    while(true)
    {
        //Main menu loop
        do
        {

            cout<<"Enter the number of the option you would like carried out.\n";
            cout<<"1. Summary\n";
            cout<<"2. Deposit\n";
            cout<<"3. Withdraw\n";
            cout<<"4. Quit\n";
            cin>>x;
        }
        while(!x);

        //When Quit is input, break
        if(x==4)
        {
            break;
        }
            //Summary display
            if (x==1)
            {
                cout<<"You have selected option number 1. Summary.\n"<<endl;
                cout<<"Enter your Cust_ID: "; 
                cin>>ID;
                file.open("C:\\Users\\Raggulddon\\Desktop\\C++ supplement
                           \\Cust_"+ID+".dat", ios::in|ios::out|ios::app);

                //IF not found error.
                if(!file)
                {
                    cout<<"Sorry your account could not be found\n";
                }
                //Else display all content.
                else
                {
                        cout<<endl<<file.rdbuf()<<"\n";
                        file.close();

                }           
            }
            //Deposit
            else if(x==2)
            {
                cout<<"You have selected option number 2. Deposit.\n";
                cout<<"Please enter you account ID: ";
                cin>>ID;
                file.open("C:\\Users\\Raggulddon\\Desktop\\C++ supplement
                            \\Cust_"+ID+".dat", ios::in|ios::out|ios::app);

                if(!file)
                {
                    cout<<"Sorry the requested account could not be located.\n";
                }
                else
                {
                file>>firstname>>lastname;
                cout<<endl<<firstname<<" "<<lastname<<endl; 
                    while(!file.eof())
                    {
                        file>>date>>amount;
                        //
                        //This is mainly where I am missing the lines of code..
                        //                      
                        float atof(string& amount);
                        cout<<date<<"\t\t"<<amount<<endl;
                    }


                        cin.get();cin.get();
                    cout<<"How much would you like to deposit today.";
                    cin>>amountinput;

                    cout<<endl;
                    file.close();

                }
            }

                else if(x==3);
                else if(x==4);


    }       
    cin.get();cin.get(); //or system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

A sample text file looks like this.

James Bond

01/01/12    200010

03/30/12    -40000

04/30/12    -40000

05/30/12    -40000

06/30/12    -40000

07/30/12    -40000

I have converted the date and amount into strings and have attempted
to convert it into a float and double, and add them up. 
I have thought of separating the amounts but I can't manage to do that either.
I have also tried to make make amount a char type.

Any advice to lead me on the right path would be kindly appreciated.

Comment: Part of your problem is probably the notorious `while(!file.eof())` -- pretty much a guaranteed bug.

Comment: No that's not it, no reason for that to be a bug. Program runs fine, its just my vision isn't coming to reality.
Although I did atof, I can't change the value(even though im trying to get valueS) at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it doesn't attempt to be a complete version of your program, here's a bit of code to read the supplied text file, using the first item (after the name) as an initial balance, and the rest as deposits (if they're positive) or withdrawals (if they're negative), reporting the amount of each transaction, and the balance after it's been applied.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

struct transaction {
    std::string date;
    double value;

    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, transaction &t) {
        is >> t.date >> t.value;
        return is;
    }
    operator double() { return value; }
};

int main(){
    double value;
    transaction t;

    std::string name;
    std::getline(std::cin, name);

    std::cin >> t;
    value = t;

    while (std::cin >> t) {
        std::cout << "Transaction: " << t.value;
        value += t;
        std::cout << "\tBalance: " << value << "\n";
    }

    std::cout << value;
}
```

Comment: I tried to decipher this and implement some of it even though I'm a beginner programmer and I'm having a hard time.
Could you help a bit more please.

I have set amount = string, I then want each string to be individual from each other (so that I may add them) and have them converted to float or double, whichever.
Comments are helpful but not required :)